# How can I have multiple forms start at once in C# .NET?

Tags: c#

In C#, I'm trying to get two forms (but probably three eventually) to start at the same time... I've tried adding a new "Application.Run" to my Program.cs file, but it only starts the second form after the first one closes.

So how could I create something like that? Similar to a program like Lazarus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display a Form you have 2 methods:

- Show() - display a non modal dialog (is what you want); also you need to add Application.Run for to work.
- ShowDialog() - display a modal(some blocking) dialog; a modal dialog capture all the input for the current thread.

If you want a interface like Lazarus, google by the "MDI application".

Answer (score 4):

You simply have to show your form before invoking Application.Run().

```
var form1 = new Form1();
var form2 = new Form2();
form1.Show();
form2.Show();

Application.Run();
```

Word of warning here, since no form is tied to the `Application.Run` call, you will need a way to tell the application to exit when all your forms are closed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably should decide on one form to be your "primary" form, and then have the other form(s) be member variables of your main form.  Then just have the Load event of your primary form also show the secondary form(s).

so,

```
class MainForm : Form {
    readonly Form _otherForm = new OtherForm();
    override OnLoad(EventArgs args) {
        _otherForm.Closed += // add a handler for what happens when otherForm is closed.
        _otherForm.Show();
        base.OnLoad(args);
    }
 }
```

There may be a better way of doing this but that's what I would do as a first shot.